# Caching Facebook Profiles With Appcache

Tags: html, html5-appcache, kik

I am having an issue caching facebook profile pictures using appcache. In my Cache Manifest, I have a number of external resources successfully cached so I tried to save profiles in the same manner (for eg, http://graph.facebook.com/21305053/picture?type=large).

However, when the page loads I get the following error: "Application Cache Progress event: Resource fetch failed (4) http://graph.facebook.com/21305053/picture?type=large"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens an is served over HTTPS and the manifest references files on another origin. AppCache has a same-origin policy when served over HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I already new that appcache couldnt handle HTTPS but I thought it would be fine using the urls above since they are HTTP. However, I just realized that Facebook redirects the urls to HTTPS, and look like the following: "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net"